# Segmentation faulty tree: while running any command using apt

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

When I run any command with apt, I get a segmentation fault.

`Segmentation faulty tree... 50%`

(Sometimes it shows `Segmentation faulty tree (Core dumped)`)

I tried many solutions listed in the forum, but none of them worked.

The commands I tried were:

`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin`

`sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin`

They run without showing any error, but the segmentation fault is still there.

This error started when I pressed `Ctrl + C` while trying to install aptitude using apt.

Comment: Try reinstalling apt. Download the apt package for 18.04 from http://packages.ubuntu.com, then use dpkg to reinstall apt: `sudo dpkg --install /full/path/to/downloaded/package.deb `

Comment: Inspect the files in `/var/crash/`

Comment: @user535733 Thank you tons!! This worked wonders!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an ordinary application (like apt) start segfaulting, and it seems like nothing has changed that might otherwise account for the problem, then try reinstalling the package.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall the_package_name
```

In this case, since apt is the problem, you can't do that. Instead, use `dpkg` to reinstall apt.

This is usually pretty easy:

- The original .deb package is sitting in your /var/cache/apt/archives
- `dpkg` will automatically overwrite the older package files with newer when simply told to --install (so you DON'T need to specify --reinstall to dpkg).

So poke around in your filesystem to find the .deb file and you get...

```
sudo dpkg --install /var/cache/apt/archives/exact_name_of_the_deb_file.deb
```

However, in this case, there's an additional problem: Sometimes folks delete the deb file from their /var/cache! They usually don't mean to - they just don't quite understand how apt works, and perhaps don't quite understand the magic shell incantations that they are inputting.

(Advice: DON'T input magic shell incantations. Take the time to understand what a command does before you run it. It might make things worse.)

You can overcome this problem by downloading the package using a web browser from http://packages.ubuntu.com. DON'T cleverly download the newest package from the newest release (that causes new problems). Just download the appropriate package for your release of Ubuntu.

Save the .deb package where you can find it. Then:

```
sudo dpkg --install /full/path/to/the/package.deb
```

If this didn't solve the segfault problem, then you have some other problem (like a wrong-release package) that simple reinstallation won't solve.